# Wrong colors displayed after React renders div to DOM

Tags: html, reactjs, dom, jsx

I was writing some code to map random colors to cells in row.

```
const COLORS = ['blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'purple', 'yellow'];

const createRandomColors = () => {
  const randomColors = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < COLORS.length; i++) {
    const randomColor = COLORS[Math.floor(Math.random() * COLORS.length)];
    randomColors.push(randomColor);
  }
  return randomColors;
}

const App = () => {
  const row = useMemo(createRandomColors, []);

  console.log(row);

  const cells = useMemo(() => row.map((cell, cellIndex) =>
    <div key={cellIndex} style={{ backgroundColor: cell }}>{cellIndex}</div>
  ), [row]);

  cells.forEach(cell => console.log(cell.props.style.backgroundColor));

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="row">
        {cells}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The problem is that after rendering ***div*** elements they have completely different inline style background-color that was specified when mapping divs.

[image: Rendered colors differ from those specified in JSX]

Please see [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/infallible-platform-1yp6z?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and take a look at console log and real results rendered.
Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this appears wonky is related to using `<StrictMode>` in your `index.html` file. If you remove `<StrictMode>` you'll see your code works the way you expect. But don't do that, you really do have a bug.

React wants functional components to be idempotent, meaning they do not have side effects. To help you catch side-effects, React will call your code twice back to back when it renders. [see strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) By doing this, it helps uncover subtle issues like the one you're currently experiencing.

One solution is to create the random colors once using `useEffect()`. Another is to generate the colors outside the functional component.

**UPDATE**
Please mark the answer as 'accepted' if it solves your issue. You are correct. useMemo will save the computation so it will not be re-computed unless dependencies change. However, react is purposely calling your code twice (in debug mode only) to help you catch unintentional side effects in your classes or hooks. When using strict mode, it's as if you have two of the component instead of one. i.e.

```
/* StrictMode in debug */
<StrictMode>
  <App/>
</StrictMode>

/* ... be like this: */
<>
  <App/>
  <App/>
</>
```

If you (temporarily) remove the `<StrictMode>` tag you'll see your code works as expected. And if you add code that causes your component to render again (e.g. a click counter) your useMemo should prevent the cells from being regenerated each render.

Add a console log to print every time `createRandomColors()` is called. Since your code is being called twice, you should see the debug log appear twice, but you don't. Why not? React [surpasses the console.log](https://dev.to/sebastianstamm/be-careful-with-console-log-when-using-react-strictmode-ah9) the 2nd time it calls your code.

At the top of your code (line 3) add `const log = console.log`, then replace everywhere you use `console.log` with just `log` and you'll have the full picture of what's occurring.

Keep experimenting. We've all been here.

Comment: Ok, I've put row array of colort into useState and called color creation function in useEffect. I still left  my cells logic in useMemo. It works now. But I still don't get it how this happened. I thought using useMemo will make sure that colors will be saved and not re-rendered unless some dependencies changes. Even console logging array of cells show me react nodes with correct backgroundColor params. Does this mean that that there is another set of nodes in virtual DOM that I was not able to console log? I wonder where those come from.